# How do you change the value of a single member of a struct pointer?

Tags: c++

```
 #include <iostream>
 #include <cstring>
 using namespace std;

 struct Student {
     int no;
     char grade[14];
 };

 void set(struct Student* student);
 void display(struct Student student);

 int main( ) {
     struct Student harry = {975, "ABC"};

     set(&harry);
     display(harry);
 }
 void set(struct Student* student){
     struct Student jim = {306, "BBB"};

     *student = jim; // this works
     //*student.no = 306; // does not work
 }
 void display(struct Student student){

     cout << "Grades for " << student.no;
     cout << " : " << student.grade << endl;
 }
```

How can I change just one member of the structure with a pointer? Why does *student.no = 306 not work? Just a bit confused.

Comment: I highly suggest you look into how OOP changed with C++.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a pointer to a struct, you should use `->` to access it's members:

```
student->no = 306;
```

This is syntactic sugar for doing `(*student).no = 306;`. The reason yours didn't work is  because of [operator precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence). Without the parentheses, the `.` has higher precedence than `*`, and your code was equivalent to `*(student.no) = 306;`.

Answer (score 0):

`operator*` has very low precedence, so you have to control the evaluation with parenthesis:

```
(*student).no = 306;
```

Though it can always be done as:

```
student->no = 306;
```

which in my opinion is much easier.

Answer (score 0):

You should use

```
student->no = 36
```

While we are at it, it is not a good practice to pass structs by value to functions.

```
// Use typedef it saves you from writing struct everywhere.
typedef struct {
     int no;
// use const char* insted of an array here.
     const char* grade;
 } Student;

 void set(Student* student);
 void display(Student* student);

 int main( ) {
     // Allocate dynmaic. 
     Student *harry = new Student;
      harry->no = 957;
      harry->grade = "ABC";

     set(harry);
     display(harry);
 }
 void set(Student *student){

     student->no = 306; 
 }
 void display(Student *student){

     cout << "Grades for " << student->no;
     cout << " : " << student->grade << endl;

     delete student;
 }
```